# Activex control for pdf handling

Tags: asp.net, activex

do you know of any activex web component(paid or free)
that allow me to VISUALLY modify a pdf file?

I need to:
rotate, delete and reorder pages.

I know i can do that using itext but thats not a visual tool.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering,
i ended up using a tiff viewer component after converting my pdf to tiff.